# Importing project into Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

My client just sent me the base project for development purposes. I think he just zipped the project folder and sent to me.

Now when I go to NetBeans, "New project with existing sources":
First I see the error that "**this project already contains build folder**". I deleted the build folder from project and then I get the error "**this project already contains a netbeans project**".

Any idea what I am missing. I am used to Eclipse and new to Netbeans. The project structure sent to me by client is:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try copying the **src** and **web** folder in different folder location and *create New project with existing sources* in Netbeans. This should work. Or remove the nbproject folder as well before importing.

Comment: I have a similar problem, I have copied the src and pom.xml file to a separate folder, but netbeans still thinks it is part of another project?

Answer (score 6):

Follow these steps:

1. Open Netbeans
2. Click File > New Project > JavaFX > JavaFX with existing sources
3. Click Next
4. Name the project
5. Click Next
6. Under *Source Package Folders* click Add Folder
7. Select the *nbproject* folder under the zip file you wish to upload (Note: you need to unzip the folder)
8. Click Next
9. All the files will be included but you can exclude some if you wish
10. Click Finish and the project should be there

If you don't have the source folder added do the following

1. Under your projects directory tree right click on Source Packages
2. Click New
3. Click Java Package and name it with the name of the package the source files have
4. Go to the directory location (i.e., using Windows Explorer not Netbeans) of those source files, highlight them all, then drag and drop them under that Java Package you just created
5. Click Run
6. Click Clean and Build Project

Now you can have fun and run the application.

Answer (score 3):

**From Netbeans 8.1** - there is an "Import from ZIP" option.

Go to **Main Menu -> File -> Import Project -> from ZIP.**

Browse your .ZIP file's location via Browse button.

If you have Java project depending on external Libraries, Netbeans will highlight & ask for "Resolving problems" in project, click on resolve, provide location in your file system containing required library files .e.g JARs etc & you will be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

If there is already a nbproject folder it means you can open it straight ahead without importing it as a project with existing sources (ctrl+shift+o) or (cmd+shift+o)

Answer (score 2):

File >> New Project >> Java Project With Existing Source>Next >> Project Name(add a name for your project) >> Next>>Add Folder >> select your existing project source code from your Directory>>Next >> Finish

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Java Project With Existing Source

Answer (score 0):

I use Netbeans 7. Choose menu **File** \ **New project**, choose **Import from existing folder**.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have all the files in a folder, say "Project", you simply have to open Netbeans and go to 
`File -> Open Project` (or `Ctrl + Shift+ O` on Windows) and then from the dialog box navigate to the folder containing the Folder "Project".

You will see in the dialog box of Netbeans a 'Java cup'. Well, that's your project.

Answer (score -1):

You may try creating a new project in netbeans and then copy and and paste the files into it. I usually experience this problem when the project wasn't created in netbeans.