# Import project to NetBeans from github

Tags: java, github, netbeans, import

Yesterday I tried to import [a project from github](https://github.com/vigna/Sux4J) to NetBeans, but was unable to do so. I tried to copy the file to a new project that I created manually. It failed too. A lot of errors were thrown that I did not understand.

Comment: Please update the question with error logs and other supportive stuff, it will increase the chance of getting answered.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824960/importing-project-into-netbeans

Comment: It depends entirely on the content, from the github page there is no direct netbeans project file, so you can either try to import from the makefile and have it setup the project or you can create a new project from the src files in the project.

Answer (score 0):

If you managed to import it and still have errors it is probably an ide issue, try to import the project from eclipse.
Sometimes when programming in eclipse you cant import it properly from netbeans and vice-versa.