# How to open downloaded Java project in NetBeans

Tags: java, jsf, jdbc, netbeans, jframe

I have download a Java web project from the Internet and now I want to do some changes in it. It is not getting opened in NetBeans. Can anyone help me?

This is the folder structure of the project:

[image]

Comment: What version of NetBeans are you using? What have you tried? Have you researched answers in questions such as [Importing project into Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17824960/12567365), or [some of these related questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=import+project+into+netbeans+site%3Astackoverflow.com)?

Comment: As one answer has already noted, it looks like the downloaded project is an Eclipse project. Therefore, please update your question to specify the page containing the link you used for the download. This helps others attempt to replicate/resolve your problem, and provide a more useful answer. Also, update the question to specify your versions of NetBeans and Java.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the folders/files `.settings`, `.classpath` and `.project` this looks like to be an eclipse project - not like a NetBeans project.

If you still want to use NetBeans `File > Import Project > Eclipse Project ...` should be the way to open it in NetBeans.